# How to show Errors in php

Tags: php

in this blow file i want to show error if the login name or password is worng.now a time i am using echo. so can u tell me how i can use error message in this.

MY code is

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors','5');
    include("conn.php");
    session_start();
    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        // username and password sent from Form
        $u_name=addslashes($_POST['username']);
        $password=addslashes($_POST['password']);

        $sql="SELECT id FROM admin WHERE username='$u_name' and password='$password'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);
        $db_field=mysql_fetch_array($result);
        $active=$row['active'];
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);


        // If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
        if($count==1)
        {
            session_register("u_name");
            $_SESSION['login_user']=$u_name;
            header("location: main.php");
        }
        else
        {
              echo ("Your Login Name or Password is invalid");
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: don't use mysql_* its depricated now...

Comment: You really should not store passwords in plain text. Also you are using deprecated mysql extension and are only nominally preventing against SQL injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy that I normally use  is declare an `$error` variable globally and update it accordingly in my php code and even append errors as they occur ,like name invalid,password invalid,etc. to this string and display it finally in a `<div>`.

Suppose you want to dislplay error at the footer fixed to the screen

```
<html>
<body>

.......
......
<div id="errors" style="display:fixed;bottom:0px;left:20px;>

<?php echo $error?>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM admin WHERE username='$u_name' and password='$password'
```

instead because your code returns 1 row (probably a NULL cell) even if there is no combination you search for. Use `COUNT(*)` then make another query for getting the ID if the returned result is >0

Answer (score 0):

You should check this condition

```
if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
```

kindly check output of `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]` 
Thanks.